# mariaDB replication stops when creating image in aws

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-replication, mariadb, aws-cli

Currently using aws as my db hosting.  Instead of using RDS I am using instances to include mariaDB and distribute few instances over different region for replication.

Everything works fine but because using instances, aws does not back up automatically so now I am creating a `crontab` job to run an `aws cli` to create image automatically.  I am still in testing phase but then I found out, each time when I run the script and aws does create an image of the instance BUT the catch is, mariaDB would stop completely and would not start up automatically.

## I actually got it fixed but wonder if people know about this and if there is a way to prevent this.

I have googled then tried running `galera_new_cluster` on the `1st node` which then showed error about file named `grastate.dat` that I can change the `bootstrap` value from `0 to 1`.

I did that, then run the `galera_new_cluster` again which then worked perfectly to start up `mariadb`, then I have to go to other `dbs` and start them manually.

At first, I thought this would be then fixed but guess not.  I tried running the `aws cli` to create image of the instance again.  The dbs all went down again.  the `bootstrap` value is back to `0` that I have to set it to `1` and run all those commands again and to other server too.

I thought of writing a script to do it step by step each time after creating an image but it would be kinda a hassle.

Does anyone know about this situation or a way to fix it permanently?

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: When you say "creating an image," I assume you mean an AMI, `aws ec2 create-image`. That will reboot your instance, by default.  Perhaps the first question is, does your setup properly survive a reboot?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes, I meant `aws ec2 create-image` if I reboot the instance myself. It boot up itself though, or there's a settings I should check to make sure?

Comment: It shouldn't be different whether it's rebooted by AMI creation or a console reboot.  I believe they both emulate control-alt-delete being pressed, but I'd have to verify.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot but by reboot, I rebooted inside the terminal though.  I SSH in and manually `sudo reboot` which of course kicks me out then waited a bit, I ssh in again checked the mysql status, it is running